# Removing duplicate code from an SQL query

Tags: sql, query-optimization, ssms

I have created an SQL query which works as expected but uses a lot of repeated code in the SELECT statement to calculate a value.

For instance in my SQL statement this line:

```
SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01)
```

Is repeated for several SELECT conditions within a different formula.

E.g.

```
(rd.OurQty - SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01) + od.Number01) AS 'Left In Stock'
```

and

```
CASE WHEN (rd.OurQty - SUM(od.Number01) 
OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01) + od.Number01) - od.Number01 > 0 THEN od.Number01 ELSE (CASE WHEN (rd.OurQty - SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01) 
+ od.Number01) > 0 THEN (rd.OurQty - SUM(od.Number01) OVER (ORDER BY od.Number01) + od.Number01) ELSE 0 END) END AS 'Allocated'
```

For small datasets this isn't too much of a problem. A problem arises however when the dataset becomes larger.

How can I store the result from this statement once per row calculation, and then use this result stored in a local variable throughout the SELECT statement in the required calculations, rather than performing the same calculation several times?

**I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not make use of a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) to define the SUM, and then use it afterwards?

> A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary
>   result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single
>   SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement. A CTE is
>   similar to a derived table in that it is not stored as an object and
>   lasts only for the duration of the query. Unlike a derived table, a
>   CTE can be self-referencing and can be referenced multiple times in
>   the same query.

Something like

```
WITH Vals AS (
    SELECT  *,
            SUM(Number01) OVER(ORDER BY Number01) MySum
    FROM    MyTable
)
SELECT *,
        MySum
FROM Val
```

### [SQL Fiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f4ca8/1)

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle I'd have done it like this (I think you could fix it for SQL Server's dialect):

```
select
  case
    when (sq.ourqty - sq.number01_sum + sq.number01) - sq.number01 > 0
      then
        sq.number01
    else
      case
        when (sq.ourqty - sq.number01_sum + sq.number01) > 0
          then 
            sq.ourqty - sq.number01_sum + sq.number01
          else
            0
      end
  end as allocated
  , ...
from
(
select sum(od.number01) over (order by od.number01) as number01_sum
       , od.number01 as number01
       , rd.ourqty as ourqty
       , ...
from anytable1 od
     , anytable2 rd
where ...
) sq
```